# WebApi2 default json serializer doesn't throw expected exception

Tags: json, serialization, webapi2

I am sending json like this
{
    "NumericField" : "abc"
}
property is declared in object DataRequest  like....
[DataMember]
public int NumericField;

Controller recieves data with [FromBody] DataRequest request.

It is quietly setting value to 0.

There are other fields that are set properly, but why no exception..

Thanks

Comment: share your code

Comment: Just use default webapi2 project. And FromBody tag.

Comment: And we ended up overriding serializer converters. And added Error delegate. We put the error in the response header yuck. But then in controller request was null and response header checked for error. I don't recommend using FromBody tag. Just do the above a serialize request first line of controller...